# How to create a custom menu in Drupal 7?

Tags: routes, 7

I need to create custom menu in Drupal 7. I don't need to add links on Main menu, but instead I need to create **new** menu with new menu links.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 4):

## Step 1: Create the menu

Navigate to `admin/structure/menu/add` in your site and add the menu you want. Add at least the "Title" of the menu (like *Custom menu*), save it, and it will show up in `admin/structure/menu` also. From there you can start to add menu items (which will be the "new links" you are looking for).

## Step 2: Make the menu visible

Head over to `admin/structure/block` to indicate in which region of your theme you want that newly added menu (*Custom menu*) to be shown.

## Step 3: Clear the cache

And don't forget to clear the cache (since you're changing things that are cache sensitive ...). I think "menu" cache should be sufficient, but to be sure I usually just clear all caches ...

Comment: I have created but its not showing me menu block in block section.like other menus .. main menu. navigation etc.

Answer (score 1):

After adding your new menu, you might have to clear the caches so Drupal can rebuild the menus. Click "Empty all caches" at `admin/config/development/performance`.